# Using tesseract on Pydroid

Tags: python, tesseract, pydroid

I am using Pydroid on an android tablet just to play around a bit with python. My PC is out of comission for a bit.

I am trying to build a OCR project to practice a bit but I need to use tesseract. There is a line where I have to point to tesseract:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd='System_path_to_tesseract.exe'
```

This doesn't work on pydroid and I was hoping someone could show me how to install it on android or maybe an alterantive I can use

Answer (score 0):

pytesseract requires that you install tesseract executable by yourself in advance (which is IMO quite challenging for tablets...)
Anyway, I found the post [Cross Compile Tesseract For Android On Windows 10](https://bucket401.blogspot.com/2021/07/crosscompile-tesseract-for-android-on.html), so it should be doable.