# com.chaquo.python.PyException: TesseractNotFoundError: ...Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your PATH

Tags: java, android, tesseract, chaquopy

I'm trying to connect pytesseract from python code to android studio (java) using chaquopy.

I keep getting this error every time I try to run the code.

```
com.chaquo.python.PyException: TesseractNotFoundError: C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

I'm pretty sure I have downloaded tesseract and stated in the right path. I also added the path to the environment variable, but it's still showing this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZofT.png)

Anyone have any idea how to solve this issue? Thank you in advance

Comment: Related: [Please include Pytesseract package #220](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/220) which has a blocker on [Support packages which depend on external native executables #605](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/605) and will at least require a ARM executable as `.exe` implies Windows. Somewhat related: [Using tesseract on Pydroid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71900195/295004)

Comment: Related: [Android Studio with Chaquopy: Tesseract Not Installed or Not in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74756725)